# Pulling custom field into Rally Query

Tags: excel, rally

I am creating a Query using the Rally/Excel plug-in.  I am creating the report with a base type of Task but want to include User Story information in the Query.

I have been able to do this before by adding "WorkProduct.Release" into the columns listing.  That works no problem.  When I attempt this with a custom field named "CR#" I get no contents being returned.

I am able to pull custom fields from the Task itself without issue it just appears to be an issue when pulling from the parent object.

I have verified the field name and that the content is actually populated.  Does anyone know a way to pull this data via the excel plug-in or if there is a limitation with pulling custom field information from a parent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Web Serivces API Workproduct attribute is Artifact. Artifact is a parent of Task, HierarchicalRequirement (user story) and Defects, and other work item types. Those types can have custom fields created on them, but the parent Artifact is not aware of them. It is not possible to traverse from Artifact to a custom field, and it should also not be possible to traverse to Iteration or Release from Artifact. Those fields do not exist on Artifact object in the API. It is possible to traverse Workproduct.FormattedID because FormattedID attribute exists on Artifact. That's where work item types inherit the FormattedID from. If I use Workproduct.Release or Workproduct.Iteration  in Excel plugin in a query on a Task object following this syntax:

```
(Workproduct.Iteration = /iteration/12352898163)
```

I get this error:

[image]

```
(Workproduct.Iteration.Name = it123)
```

will produce a similar error.

Comment: Workproduct.Iteration actually works just fine, (leave the .name portion off)

Comment: That is true at least for the excel plug-in.

Answer (score 0):

I put this to the Rally Support folks and got the following answer, so the short answer is no...can't be done:

> When you query using WorkProduct.FormattedID on a task, the data can
>   be returned because that field is part of "Artifact".  You can see
>   this by looking at the Web Services API information, which I have
>   included some screenshots to illustrate this.  The custom field you
>   are trying to query doesn't reside on Artifact, so is not found by the
>   query.
>
> The actual work product that has your custom field would be either a
>   defect or a story, but the Task object does not reference back to that
>   to allow you to query.
>
> You could do another query for the different work products and include
>   the custom field, then combine the two worksheets.